# Изменение функций кнопок стилуса

Tags: python

Есть сенсорный планшет с виндовс 10 и ёмкостный стилус, но нет ПО для изменения функций кнопок стилуса. У стилуса две кнопки: одна это аналог правой кнопки мыши, а вторая это стирание нарисованного. Интересно как можно реализовать изменение функций кнопок стилуса, например чтобы задать кнопке стилуса функцию кнопки Ctrl.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Хм, а при чём тут питон? Такие вещи вряд ли делают на питоне.

Comment: пишите свой драйвер https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-your-first-driver